# How to properly pull from cache before remote using swift combine

Tags: swift, combine

I perform many repeated requests in order to populate a field. I would like to cache the result and use the cached value the next time around.

```
public func getItem(_ id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Item?, Never> {
    if let item = itemCache[id] {
        return Just(item).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    return downloadItem(id: id)
        .map { item in
            if let item = item {
                itemCache[id] = item
            }
            return item
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

func downloadItem(_ id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Item?, Never> { ... }
```

And this is called like this:

```
Just(["a", "a", "a"]).map(getItem)
```

However, all the requests are calling `downloadItem`. `downloadItem` does return on the main queue. I also tried wrapping the entire `getItem` function into Deferred but that had the same result.

Answer (score 1):

First, the issue was that the function is being evaluated and only a publisher is returned. So the cache check is evaluated each time before the network publisher is ever subscribed to. Using `Deferred` is the proper fix for that. However, that still didn't solve the problem.

The solution was instead to first cache a shared publisher while the network request is pending so all requests during the network call will use the same publisher, then when it's complete to cache a `Just` publisher for the all future calls:

```
public func getItem(_ id: String) -> AnyPublisher<Item?, Never> {
    if let publisher = self.publisherCache[id] {
        return publisher
    }

    let publisher = downloadItem(id)
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
            // Re-cache a Just publisher once the network request finishes
            self.publisherCache[id] = Just($0).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        })
        .share() // Ensure the same publisher is returned from the cache
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    // Cache the publisher to be used while downloading is in progress
    self.publisherCache[id] = publisher

    return publisher
}
```

One note, is that `downloadItem(id)` is async and being recieved on the main loop. When I replaced `downloadItem(id)` with `Just(Item())` for testing, this didn't work beause the entire publisher chain was evaluated on creation. Use `Just(Item()).recieve(on: Runloop.main)` to fix that while testing.